# Invalid STRING constant OR mismatched input ':' expecting '}' - Cassandra DB

Tags: java, cassandra, cql

I have two issues:

1. When I am executing the code below:

   public void insertFarmers(int id, HashMap<String, String> the_farmer, List delivery) {

   ```
    Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
            .addContactPoints(serverIP)
            .build();
    try (Session session = cluster.connect("farm_db")) {
        String insert_query = "INSERT INTO farmers (farmer_id, delivery, the_farmer) VALUES ( "
                + "'" +id+ "',"
                + "'" +delivery + "',"
                + "'" +the_farmer + "')";

       session.execute(insert_query);
    }
   ```

   }

... along with this code in my main-class:

```
HashMap<String, String> the_farmer = new HashMap<>();
    the_farmer.put("Name ", " The name ");
    the_farmer.put("Farmhouse ", " Varpinge Gard");
    the_farmer.put("Foods ", " Fruits & Vegetables");

    List<String> delivery = new ArrayList<>();
    delivery.add("Malmo Hus parkering");
    delivery.add("Lund Golfbana Varpinge");


    employeeService.insertFarmers(1, the_farmer, delivery);
```

...I get this error:

```
InvalidQueryException: Invalid STRING constant ([Malmo Hus parkering, Lund Golfbana Varpinge]) for "delivery" of type list<text>
```

2. When I try this instead, below I get this error:

```
        Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
                .addContactPoints(serverIP)
                .build();
        try (Session session = cluster.connect("farm_db")) {
            SimpleStatement insert_query = new
                    SimpleStatement("INSERT INTO farmers (farmer_id, delivery, the_farmer) VALUES " +
                    "(1, {'Name' : 'The name' , 'Farmhouse' : 'Varpinge Gard' : 'Foods' : 'Fruits & Vegetables'}, " +
                    "['Malmo Hus parkering','Lund Golfbana (Varpinge)']);", id, delivery, the_farmer);
              session.execute(insert_query);
        }
    } 


The error message: 
SyntaxError: line 1:118 mismatched input ':' expecting '}' (...'The name' , 'Farmhouse' : 'Varpinge Gard' [:] 'Food...)
```

Comment: Perhaps it would help to take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: No, not really since this is documentation about SQL, not CQL:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So type handling with collections can be tricky.  I was able to reproduce your error.

I was able to get this to work by using a prepared statement:

```
String insert_query = "INSERT INTO farmers (farmer_id, delivery, the_farmer) VALUES (?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement pStatement = session.prepare(insert_query);
BoundStatement bStatement = pStatement.bind(id, delivery, the_farmer);
    
session.execute(bStatement);
```

For the second question, it looks like you have transposed variables for `delivery` and `the_farmer`.

> What is the difference between 'PreparedStatement' and 'SimpleStatement'?

A `SimpleStatement` will parse the query on every execution, so it can be a little costly for statements that repeat.  On the other hand, a `PreparedStatement` will parse the query only once, and then store it in the prepared statement cache (in the cluster) to optimize future uses.

`PreparedStatement` will also provide type checking on the client side, which I think is the core issue here.  Basically, if you can get your Java code to *compile* using a `PreparedStatement`, it shouldn't run into type issues at execution time.

Comment: @Mewken Github repo for this answer: https://github.com/aploetz/addfarmers

Comment: Hi Aaron,
I tried your solution with your code and it worked!! Thank you SO much!!

What is the difference between 'PreparedStatement' and 'SimpleStatement'?

Comment: @Mewken Edit made!

Comment: Thank you so much! :) 
(Im new at cassandra and java :D )